eslint import module error: Unable to resolve path to module
I'm a beginner using Electron for the first time, and I encountered an problem with path alias. I built a react-typescript template app using Electron-Forge, and a part of project structure is as shown in the image below:
├── node_modules
├── react-pkg
|   ├── pages
|   |   ├── Dashboard
|   |       ├── Dashboard.tsx
│   ├── components
|       ├── Avatar
|           ├── Avatar.tsx
├── src
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── preload.ts
│   └── renderer.ts
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── forge.config.ts
├── **tsconfig.json**
├── webpack.main.config.ts
├── webpack.plugins.ts
├── webpack.rules.ts
└── **webpack.renderer.config.ts**

I added some code about the 'alias' in both the tsconfig.json and webpack.renderer.config.ts.
tsconfig.json config looks like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"],
      "@/*": ["react-pkg/*"]
    },
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "react-pkg/**/*", "react-pkg/global.d.ts", "webpack.renderer.config.ts", "webpack.main.config.ts"]
}

webpack.renderer.config.ts config:
import type { Configuration } from 'webpack';
import { rules } from './webpack.rules';
import { plugins } from './webpack.plugins';
import path from 'path'

rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
});

export const rendererConfig: Configuration = {
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  plugins,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'react-pkg')
    }
  },
};

After completing these config, I set the Dashboard.tsx as default page to display. Howerver, when i tried to import Avatar.tsx on this page, received the error: Unable to resolve path to module '@/components/Avatar/Avatar'. eslint(import/no-unresolved)
Dashboard.tsx codes:
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./Dashboard.module.css";
import { Avatar } from "@/components/Avatar/Avatar"; // Unable to resolve path to module '@/components/Avatar/Avatar'. eslint(import/no-unresolved)


export default function Dashboard() {
  const handleClick = (id: string) => {
    return id;
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.layout}>
      <aside className={styles.aside}>
        <Avatar src="example.com" />
      </aside>
      <div className={styles["action-bar"]}></div>
      <main className={styles.content}>
        <Outlet></Outlet>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

I tried searching for a solution on Google and asking AI, but none of the suggestions solved the problem.

This question is similar to: Using eslint with typescript - Unable to resolve path to module. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
